# When I shutdown the computer, it restarts

Tags: 12.10, shutdown

I am unable to shutdown. Whenever I try to shutdown, it reboots. I am running Ubuntu 64bit 12.10. It is a desktop pC. No dual boot. I had windows 7 before. The graphics driver is AMD radeon HD6670.Motherboard is Intel.

I have run the boot-repair and this is the [result](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1444355):

```
    Boot Info Script 0.61.full + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info November 20th 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 1 for (,msdos1)/boot/grub.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048 1,936,809,983 1,936,807,936  83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1,936,812,030 1,953,523,711    16,711,682   5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1,936,812,032 1,953,523,711    16,711,680  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa   ext4       
/dev/sda5        6c6dca25-ab67-4de4-8602-26fdb6154781   swap       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 12.10 amd64

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=========================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=10
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa' {
recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa ro   quiet splash acpi=force $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-19-generic-advanced-229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa ro   quiet splash acpi=force $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-19-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-19-generic-recovery-229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-19-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic root=UUID=229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-advanced-229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa ro   quiet splash acpi=force $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-recovery-229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda1/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=6c6dca25-ab67-4de4-8602-26fdb6154781 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 200.155235291 = 214.915047424  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  40.280788422 = 43.251167232   boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic               1
   2.468288422 = 2.650304512    boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic               1
 200.149234772 = 214.908604416  boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic                  1
   1.990135193 = 2.136891392    boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic                  1
   2.468288422 = 2.650304512    initrd.img                                     1
   1.990135193 = 2.136891392    vmlinuz                                        1
   1.990135193 = 2.136891392    vmlinuz.old                                    1

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: write error: Broken pipe
File descriptor 8 (/proc/6297/mounts) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent PID 13390: bash
  No volume groups found

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2012-12-17__01h53 ===================
boot-repair version : 3.197~ppa1~quantal
boot-sav version : 3.197~ppa1~quantal
glade2script version : 3.2.2~ppa45~quantal
boot-sav-extra version : 3.197~ppa1~quantal
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 12.10, quantal, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash -- maybe-ubiquity

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda1:Ubuntu 12.10 (12.10):Ubuntu:linux

=================== blkid:
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 12.10 amd64" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/sda1: UUID="229a5484-7659-4ce1-98ce-2f05f61a1ffa" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="6c6dca25-ab67-4de4-8602-26fdb6154781" TYPE="swap"


1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 0 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.


=================== sda1/etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"




=================== sda1/etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 17 14:59 grub.d
total 72
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7541 Oct 14 17:36 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5488 Oct  4 09:30 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10891 Oct 14 17:36 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10258 Oct 14 17:36 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1688 Oct 11 14:10 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10976 Oct 14 17:36 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1426 Oct 14 17:36 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Oct 14 17:36 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Oct 14 17:36 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 Oct 14 17:36 README


=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not in EFI-mode.
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  grub-pc ,   update-grub,    64, with-boot,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.

sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    has-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA ST1000DM003-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  992GB   992GB   primary   ext4            boot
2      992GB   1000GB  8556MB  extended
5      992GB   1000GB  8556MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)




Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA ST1000DM003-1CH1;
1:1049kB:992GB:992GB:ext4::boot;
2:992GB:1000GB:8556MB:::;
5:992GB:1000GB:8556MB:linux-swap(v1)::;



Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!


=================== mount:
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/ubuntu/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type ext4 (rw)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda5 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  alarm ashmem autofs binder block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency disk dri dvd dvdrw ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse fw0 hidraw0 hidraw1 hpet input kmsg kvm log mapper mcelog mei mem net network_latency network_throughput null oldmem port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda5 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uinput urandom usb vga_arbiter vhost-net zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlayfs  3.9G  100M  3.8G   3% /
udev           devtmpfs   3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      1.6G  864K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sr0       iso9660    763M  763M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs   717M  717M     0 100% /rofs
tmpfs          tmpfs      3.9G   32K  3.9G   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      3.9G  176K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs      100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1      ext4       910G   26G  838G   3% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000da1e9

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1936809983   968403968   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1936812030  1953523711     8355841    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1936812032  1953523711     8355840   82  Linux swap / Solaris


Partition outside the disk detected.

=================== Recommended repair
Recommended-Repair
This setting will reinstall the grub2 of sda1 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/etc/default/grub
grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-7ubuntu11,grub-install (GRUB) 2.

Reinstall the GRUB of sda1 into the MBR of sda
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add details of your computer brand/model/graphics card/wireless etc.

Comment: Are you logged into any other virtual terminal, at the same time?

Comment: not logged into any other virtual terminal

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It went away when I deleted `~/.Xauthority`.

Answer (score 3):

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on an HP Envy M6 (amd version) and I had the same problem. I used this command: `sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools`
and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install upstart.
I had that problem before and when I re-installed upstart it went better.

```
sudo apt-get install upstart --reinstall
```

Comment: I tried this. It didnt work.

Comment: Had similar problem, it's not help